# Xcode IB warns about ambiguous position for UIStackView in UICollectionViewCell though it shouldn't be

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I tried trailing,leading,bottom,top as well as center/width/height constraint-sets. In both cases Xcode complains about ambiguous position unless I wrap the stackview in a UIView inside the cell.
Is this supposed to work like this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have too many constraints and they likely conflict.  The system needs one position and one size for each dimension.  If you give it two positions then it automatically infers the dimension -- ie if you give it top and bottom then it auto calculates the height, so you shouldn't also be specifying the height.  On top of that the stack view can actually determine its own height if all of its elements have an intrinsic size.  In that case you can just specify a single position constraint.

TLDR just use top, bottom, leading, trailing constraints and the system will infer the width and height.

Comment: I'm sorry if my phrasing was ambiguous. I was referring to the sets of top/bottom/leading/trailing and center/width/height separately, of course.